# Reactjs search / filter function

Tags: reactjs, search, ecmascript-6, filter, react-tsx

I tried to implement search/filter function on reactjs app. User can search anything and object should return based on search value. Search logic implemented in `handleChange`. Can anyone let me know where I made mistake?

> It's doesn't return any errors. Just screen gone blank

**Shipment.tsx**

```js
export class Shipment extends Component<object, ListInterface> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [] as any[],
      value: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getShipmentList();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: any) {
    this.setState({
      list: nextProps.list
    });
  }

  getShipmentList() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/shipments').then((res: any) => {
      this.setState({ list: res.data });
    });
  }

  handleChange(e: any) {
    let currentList = [];
    let newList = [];

    if (e.target.value !== '') {
      currentList = this.state.list;

      newList = currentList.filter((item: any) => {
        const lc = item.toString().toLowerCase();
        const filter = e.target.value.toString().toLowerCase();

        return lc.includes(filter);
      });
    } else {
      newList = this.state.list;
    }
    this.setState({
      list: newList
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card className="Card">
          <CardContent className="Card-Content">
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <div className={`Card-Content__SearchBar`}>{statusList}</div>
                <div className="Card-Content__Location">
                  <TextField
                    id="outlined-name"
                    label="Search"
                    margin="normal"
                    variant="outlined"
                    fullWidth={true}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
        {this.state.list.map((item: any, index: number) => (
          <ShipmentList key={index} value={item} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Shipment;
```

**db.json**

```js
{
    "id": "S1002",
    "name": "PO89634, PO27X",
    "cargo": [
      {
        "type": "Bikes model 27X",
        "description": "100 Bikes model 27X",
        "volume": "100"
      }
    ],
    "mode": "air",
    "type": "LCL",
    "destination": "Saarbrücker Str. 38, 10405 Berlin",
    "origin": "Shanghai Port",
    "services": [
      {
        "type": "customs"
      }
    ],
    "total": "10000",
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "userId": "U1001"
  },
```

Comment: what error or undesired outcome are you getting?

Comment: How does your itemList look like? is it array of objects?

Comment: When I start typing, Im list gone empty `ShipmentList`. Show nothing in screen and no error at all.

Comment: What is in 'newList' before you set the state?

Comment: @Clarity, I've updated json in my question

Comment: You do not keep your original list. So, when you start filtering your list, you can not go back. You should have something like `filteredList` in your state and keep `list` untouched

Comment: @dar just an empty array

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp, can u show some example? How I can push `filteredList` to `ShipmentList` ?

Comment: @SKL that's not a list, it's an object.

Comment: What part of res.data are you storing in your list? Your this.list is an array, the data you're getting back is an object. You're looping through an array of one object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list has a `name` prop, so you probably want to filter based on that

```
handleChange(e: any) {
  let list = this.state.list.concat();
  const {value} = e.target; 

  if (value) {
    list = list.filter((item: any) => {
      const name = item.name.toLowerCase();
      const id = item.id.toLowerCase();
      const filter = value.toLowerCase();

      return name.includes(filter) || id.includes(filter);
    });
  } 
  this.setState({
    list
  });
}
```

Comment: is that possible filter by name and id?

Comment: Ok, added the `id` as well.

Comment: Sweet, Thanks @Clarity

Answer (score 1):

first you are using componentDidMount(), you have to use componentWillMount() function to load server data into list state then create another filtered list state which will show you filtered data when you type in the input field.
Don't overwrite your list data else you again have to fetch data from server.
Use filteredlist for search.
componentDidMount() runs after the render() function and your state won't be initialize to be used in render()

```
state =  {
list: [],
filteredlist: [],
values: ''
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.getShipmentList();
}

handleChange(){as above}
```